# FileSystemWatcher.Filter - before or after buffer?

Tags: c#, buffer, filesystemwatcher, internal

I'm working on a project with a very large amount of files being modified and created/deleted. There are some problems with multiple FSW internal buffers filling and having to be expanded.

I've found conflicting info online about whether ".Filter" filters out `BEFORE` or `AFTER` detected changes are added to the buffer. If actually after a single FSW with event sorting afterwards might make more sense.

Does anyone know here for sure which it is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`FileSystemWatcher` wraps the native W32 method [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which in turn is responsible for putting File System events in the supplied buffer. The `Filter` property is enforced on the CLR side after the event has already been buffered in a private `MatchPattern` method which tells the monitor whether to report the file event or not.

Use of the `Filter` property would unlikely help your current situation. Rather, it may be more advantageous to grow the [`InternalBufferSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.internalbuffersize.aspx) value to avoid overrunning the buffer.
Alternatively, there are a number of other file system event monitoring classes out there on the net that set out to solve this same problem.